# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el tipo Long y el tipo Integer en Java?

Tags: java

No logro ver la diferencia que hay entre ambos tipos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `Long` usa 64 bits.
- `Int` usa 32 bits.

Por lo que la cantidad de valores enteros distintos que pueden tomar es distinta.
En la siguiente imagen extraída de [aquí](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE) puedes ver los valores que comprenden.

Espero que te haya servido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]