# java.util.InputMismatchException; ¿Por qué me aparece y cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: java, excepciones

En el siguiente código se puede ver que calcula números primos, pero al calcular el valor `27603543067280716373` aparece  este error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Fragmento de código:

```java
package puntoA;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumerosPrimos {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner obtenerNumero = new Scanner(System. in );
    int contador, I, numero;

    System.out.print("Ingresa un numero: ");
    numero = obtenerNumero.nextInt();

    contador = 0;

    for (I = 1; I <= numero; I++) {
      if ((numero % I) == 0) {
        contador++;
      }
    }

    if (contador <= 2) {
      System.out.println("El numero es primo");
    } else {
      System.out.println("El numero no es primo");
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**RESPUESTA RAPIDA**

Cambiar de obtenerNumero.nextInt();

a obtenerNumero.nextLong();

**Explicación**

A mi parecer es un error simple, cuando capturar el valor lo tomas como Integer pero es un Long, de hay el error **InputMismatchException**

Te dejo la [diferencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99534/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-el-tipo-long-y-el-tipo-integer-en-java?rq=1#:%7E:text=Long%20usa%2064%20bits.,Int%20usa%2032%20bits.) de Int y Long

En otras palabras, intentas capturar un Int pero ingresas un valor de tipo Long

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner obtenerNumero = new Scanner(System.in);
    int contador,I,numero;

    System.out.print("Ingresa un numero: ");
    numero = obtenerNumero.nextLong();

    contador = 0;

    for(I = 1; I <= numero; I++)
    {
        if((numero % I) == 0)
        {
            contador++;
        }
    }

    if(contador <= 2)
    {
        System.out.println("El numero es primo");
    }else{
        System.out.println("El numero no es primo");
    }
}
```